# ES Scripted fields on large number of data

Tags: elasticsearch, scriptedfield

I have a ES index with millions of records. Currently records are fetched using scroll api and are paginated. Also all fields are sortable.
I have request for new additional fields (dependent on already existing fields). So wanted to use scripted fields.

Can we apply scripted fields clubbed with scroll api and search_after api?

Can we have scripted fields data sorted?

Example:-
We have a point collection system. Users have to collect certain points by doing some tasks in a certain time limit.

```
{
   user1: {
       "endtime": "1640807573000", // time epoch
       "points": 100,
       "target": 1000,
       ...
   },
   user2: {
       "endtime": "1640807573000" // time epoch
       "points": 200
       "target": 5000,
       ...
   }, ... // millions of such records
}
```

Values of `endtime`, `points`, `target` can be updated any time by other system.

Admins can view the report of all users on a ES based paginated tabular UI or download the whole dump of tabular report in a csv format. Now, for the Admins, we want to have visibilty of following new parameters for every user in the report.

1. `Time left`: `(user.endtime - current time)` // Current Time is the time when report is fetched for realtime report.
2. `Expected work rate`: `( target - points ) / ( Time left )`
3. `Zone`: On basis of Expected work rate ranges, classify in 3 zones; Red, Yellow, Green

Also, these 3 new fields should have sorting, filtering and pagination.

I wanted to calculate above 3 fields using scripted fields, when the report is fetched.

Any suggestion on feasibility of above approach or recommendation for better approach?

Comment: You can use scroll and sorting over scripted fields but it will be very slow with millions of records. Can these values be precomputed during indexing or `update_by_query`?

Comment: Actually the existing fields are time values, and scripted fields are actions on basis of time difference between current time and saved time. We would want the actions to be computed only when the actions are fetched, so doesn't make sense to precompute these during indexing.

Comment: Could you add an example to the post?

Comment: Added example scenario for better help in understanding the problem.

Comment: Yeah this might be tricky. I'd run a "baseline" test with runtime fields first and then based on the results would decide if performance is acceptable or should I look for alternative solutions. One option would be to precompute `Expected work rate` regularly or when updating `points` and use it for approximate retrieval and then reorder page of data if needed. Another - consider a different storage entirely (Elasticsearch doesn't work well with very frequent data updates).